# Erro ao acessar método no ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf, aplicação-web, jsf-2.2, jee

Galera estou tendo problemas ao acessar um metodo que fica no meu ManagedBean, a ideia é a seguinte: tenho uma página onde eu listo os registros que estão no db a partir do clique no botão "Consultar" e então os registros aparecem, tudo numa boa porém para cada registro tenho o botão ao lado de "Remover" e "Editar", quando clico no botão de remover ele atualiza a página e nem sequer entra no método que eu especifiquei. Por favor me ajudem nessa, e pra constar sou iniciante com as tecnologias JSF, Hibernate, etc...

Página Listagem

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Consultar Alunos"
        action="#{controllerAluno.alunosCadastrados}" />
</h:form>

<br />
<p></p>


<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="item" value="#{controllerAluno.alunos}"
        rendered="#{not empty controllerAluno.alunos}">
        <p:column headerText="Cód. Aluno">
            <center>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.id}" />
            </center>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Nome">
            <center>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.nome}" />
            </center>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Data">
            <center>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.data_Nascimento}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd, MMMM yyyy" locale="pt_BR"
                        timeZone="" />
                </h:outputText>

            </center>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Sexo">
            <center>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.sexo}" />
            </center>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="opções">
            <center>
                <h:commandButton value="Editar" />
                ||
                <h:commandButton value="Remover"
                    action="#{controllerAluno.removerAluno(item)}" />
            </center>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>

<h:form>
    <center>
        <h3>
            <h:commandLink value="Cadastrar novo Aluno"
                action="paginaInicial?faces-redirect=true" />
        </h3>
    </center>
</h:form>
```

Métodos Acessados no ManagedBean

Remover:

```
    public void removerAluno(Aluno alunoSelecionado){
    try {

        EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("conexaoDB");         
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();

        System.out.println("Entrou");
        et.begin();
        Aluno a = em.find(Aluno.class, alunoSelecionado.getId());           
        em.remove(a);           
        System.out.println("Aluno: "+a.getNome()+" removido com sucesso!");
        a =null;
        alunoSelecionado = null;

        em.close();
        factory.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Método que carrega o ArrayList

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayList<Aluno> alunosCadastrados(){

    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("conexaoDB");         
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();

    this.alunos =  (ArrayList<Aluno>) em.createQuery("FROM " + Aluno.class.getName()).getResultList();
    em.close();
    factory.close();

    return alunos;      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Teu problema está aqui:

```
<h:commandButton value="Remover"
                action="#{controllerAluno.removerAluno(item)}" />
```

Você não deve chamar métodos do `Managed Bean` passando parâmetros. A chamada referencia apenas o nome do método que só irá possuir parâmetros se for chamado por um evento. Para fazer a remoção que você deseja, é necessário informar o item a remover no `MBean`. Uma forma de fazer isso é utilizando a tag `f:setPropertyActionListener` da seguinte forma:

1 - Dentro do `commandButton` será adicionada a tag que mapeia um valor numa variável alvo do MBean:

```
<h:commandButton value="Remover" action="#{controllerAluno.removerAluno}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}" target="#{controllerAluno.alunoRemovido}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

2 - Criar um atributo em `ControllerAluno` e seus métodos `get` e `set` para que seja possível mapear o aluno a ser removido da `view`:

```
class ControllerAluno {
    private Aluno alunoRemovido;

    public Aluno getAlunoRemovido() { return alunoRemovido; }

    public void setAlunoRemovido(Aluno alunoRemovido) { 
       this.alunoRemovido = alunoRemovido;
    }
}
```

3 - Modificar o método `removerAluno` para referenciar o atributo criado:

```
public void removerAluno(){
try {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("conexaoDB");         
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();

    System.out.println("Entrou");
    et.begin();
    Aluno a = em.find(Aluno.class, alunoRemovido.getId());           
    em.remove(a);           
    System.out.println("Aluno: "+a.getNome()+" removido com sucesso!");
    a =null;
    alunoRemovido = null;

    em.close();
    factory.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

A lógica é essa para a chamada de métodos de `Managed Beans`, é sempre necessário criar uma forma de transmitir valores pois as chamadas à métodos não podem transmitir parâmetros. Existem outras formas de fazer, usei o `f:setPropertyActionListener` mas outra forma de "injeção" de valores poderia ser utilizada.

Comment: Giuliana obrigado pelas correções, ainda estou começando ai fico meio que perdido, mas, em relação ao método ainda tenho um problema que não entendo o porque acontece. Quando eu clico no botão remover, no minimo era para aparecer o "Entrou" no console, mas não, ao clicar em remover ele simplesmente volta à página que faço a listagem, não sei se você entendeu o que eu quis dizer mas resumindo, eu não consigo acessar este e nenhum outro método ao clicar no remover.

Comment: Isso é por causa das chamadas inválidas aos métodos. Mudando as chamadas como te falei não funciona? Outra coisa, você tá usando jsf 2.0? Teus MBeans estão anotados ou mapeados nas configurações?